# dplyr: How to handle multiple value

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I have a dataframe, which return 2 groups for same min. How can it be handled to reach my expected output?

```
df<- read.table(header=TRUE,
                 text="
                 Company  xxx  yyyy  zzzz  cnt
                 abc       1     1    1     20
                 aaa       1     1    2     3
                 bbb       1     1    1     3
                 ddd       2     0    2     100
                 ")
```

i tried below code

```
final= df %>%
       group_by(xxx,yyyy) %>%
         summarise(Topcomp=Company[c(which(min(cnt)==cnt))])
```

Im getting:

> Error: expecting a single value

I want to have output like below.

```
    xxx  yyyy Topcomp
  <int> <int>  <fctr>
1     1     1    aaa,bbb
2     2     0     ddd
```

Comment: The most flexible solution is a list column, i.e. `df %>% group_by(xxx, yyyy) %>% summarise(Topcomp = list(Company[cnt == min(cnt)]))`, though they take a bit of practice to work with.

Comment: Also, you can chop out `c` and `which` as I commented below, as they're not doing anything here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `paste(..., collapse  = ",")`

```
df %>%
  group_by(xxx,yyyy) %>%
  summarise(Topcomp = paste(Company[min(cnt) == cnt], collapse = ","))
```

Comment: You can take out the `c` and `which`.

Answer (score 6):

You should do this:

```
final= df %>%
   group_by(xxx,yyyy) %>%
     summarise(Topcomp=toString(Company[c(which(min(cnt)==cnt))]))
##Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
##Groups: xxx [?]
##
##    xxx  yyyy  Topcomp
##  <int> <int>    <chr>
##1     1     1 aaa, bbb
##2     2     0      ddd
```

You were getting the error because `which` returned two values so that your subset of `Company` has two values when `summarise` requires a single value. The `toString` is the similar to `paste` with `collapse=","` in that it collapses the two values into a string separated by the comma.

Also, as alistaire pointed out in his comment for the other answer, you don't need the `c` and the `which`, so this can be simplified to:

```
final= df %>%
  group_by(xxx,yyyy) %>%
    summarise(Topcomp=toString(Company[min(cnt)==cnt]))
```